# Add variable in PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error

I would like to change the location that a files uploads to by adding a PHP variable to the path name but I am unable to get it to work but I'm pretty sure it's a syntax error.

This doesn't work:

```
$this->options = array(
     'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
     'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/'.$user.'/',
     'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$user.'/',
     'param_name' => 'files'
)
```

This does:

```
$this->options = array(
     'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
     'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/bob/',
     'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/bob/',
     'param_name' => 'files'
)
```

I realize that this is not the full code, but I wondered whether there is a simple syntax error I am missing here.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$user`? What is it?

Comment: Nothing discernible here, assuming both statements close with a `);`... what comes above this code? That's probably where the syntax problem lies, but the parser doesn't find it until later on.

Comment: Hi the value of $user is bob '$user = 'bob';'

Comment: what if you change user to '/bob/'?

Comment: Won't help, he doesn't have `$user` defined in that context. Also, that's not sane advice, he might use that variable somewhere else as well, modifying it like that is not a good idea.

Comment: First and foremost always activate error displaying. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);` because obviously there is some kind of error there that is not show to you and you need to read the error message and start searching based on that.

Comment: @user1729812 I bet if you do `var_dump($user);` just before the code you pasted here you'll get null

Comment: then he could just make it $user_slashed..

Comment: Secondly if the error message is something regarding "could not move file" or "could not access file" then obviously the result of `$this->get_full_url().'/'.$user.'/'` is not what you'd expect it has something like `'//'` at the end because `$user` is probably null/not available in the current scope.

Comment: Thirdly if the error message is not regarding files/folders and the `$user` variable has the expected value in it. Then the error most likely lies somewhere else in the code, some syntactical error that you overlooked that the error_reporting will help you identify easily.

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to have defined `$user` anywhere. Even if you have, the code you gave seems to be part of a class declaration so you need to make sure `$user` is defined in the current scope (`global $user` if needed, or as a last resort try `$GLOBALS['user']`).

Comment: If this is the case, I recommend reading [the manual on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).